# How do I create connections between room structs in C?

Tags: c, pointers, unix, struct

So, I am building a rough text adventure game and I am working on the room building and trying to connect rooms to one another.

```
struct room
{
    int id;
    char* name;
    char* type;
    int numOutboundConnections;
    struct room* outboundConnections[6];
};
```

I have a pointer to my connection variable that I want to pass to the other room structs and I want the connections to be randomized from 3 min - 6 max. How would I go about adding connections in two at a time (forwards and backwards), to randomly chosen room endpoints, until the graph satisfies the requirements?

Essentially what I want would be in a format like so:

```
ROOM NAME: <room name>
CONNECTION 1: <room name>
…
ROOM TYPE: <room type>
```

Where it can be a range from 3 connections from a single room, or up to 6 possible connections from a single room.
Also, I am attempting to use this pseudocode structure provided to me as I was told this can be a simple structure to work with, I am just really confused on how to get started.

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 0
#define false 1
    // Create all connections in the graph
    while (IsGraphFull() == false)
    {
        AddRandomConnection();
    }

    // Returns true if all rooms have 3 to 6 outbound connections, false otherwise
    bool IsGraphFull()
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Adds a random outbound connection between two rooms
    void AddRandomConnection(struct room *A, struct room *B)
    {
        Room A ; // Can be a struct, or a global array of ints
        Room B;
        while(true)
        {
            A = GetRandomRoom();

            if (CanAddConnectionFrom(A) == true)
                break;
        }
        do
        {
            B = GetRandomRoom();
        }
        while(CanAddConnectionFrom(B) == false || IsSameRoom(A, B) == true || ConnectionAlreadyExists(A, B) == true);

        ConnectRoom(A, B); // TODO: Add this connection to the real variables,
        ConnectRoom(B, A); // because this A and B will be destroyed when this function terminates
    }

    // Returns a random Room, does NOT validate if connection can be added
    Room GetRandomRoom()
    {
        return rand(Room);
    }
    // Returns true if a connection can be added from Room x (< 6 outbound connections), false otherwise
    bool CanAddConnectionFrom(Room x)
    {
        if (Room x < outboundConnections[6])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Returns true if a connection from Room x and Room y already exists, false otherwise
    bool ConnectionAlreadyExists(x, y)
    {
        if (Room x == ConnectionAlreadyExists(x, y) || Room y == ConnectionAlreadyExists(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Connects Rooms x and y together, does not check if this connection is valid
    void ConnectRoom(Room x, Room y)
    {
        ConnectRoom(A, B);
        ConnectRoom(B, A);
    }
    // Returns true if Rooms x and y are the same Room, false otherwise
    bool IsSameRoom(Room x, Room y)
    {
        if (Room x == Room y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for the `AddRandomConnection` function you have the argument `struct room *A` then inside the function you *shadow* that argument variable with `Room A`.

Comment: Also remember that variables are by default passed *by value* which means that they will be *copied*. And modifying a copy will not modify the original.

Comment: Lastly, he code you show doesn't look like C. You mix statements and function definitions in the same scope.

Comment: Sounds like a job for recursion. Create a room. For each of the 6 connections, randomly choose to create a room. Repeat for each new room.

Comment: `if (Room x == Room y)` syntax error. Does this even compile? Also: `Room` is never defined.

Comment: You show `typedef int bool;` — `#define true 0` — `#define false 1` but C99 added `<stdbool.h.>` which uses the built-in type `_Bool` instead of `int` but is otherwise essentially equivalent.  Try to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: why outbound connections only? shouldn't they just be connections, I mean you have to be able to go back and fourth unless of course they are one ways. How many rooms total?